# Using IndexDecider in Serilogs Elasticsearch Sink

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, serilog

Im trying to use a custom indexdecider to set the index name at run time for my serilog elasticsearch sink. (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch)

Whichever function I use for the index decider gets ignored and the index name defaults to logstash-yyyy-mm-dd unless I give it another index name pattern. I need it to use the index decider function.

```
var esConfig = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticSearchLogServer))
       {
           BufferBaseFilename = Path.Combine(logPath, bufferfilename),
           IndexDecider = (@event, offset) =>
                          {
                              var indexNumber = Math.Ceiling((double)offset.Day / 8);
                              var indexName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3:yyyy.MM}-{4}", "logbase", environment, shortAppname, offset, indexNumber);
                              return indexName;
                          }
       };
var loggerConfiguration = loggerSinkConfiguration.Elasticsearch(esConfig);
```

Comment: I found the bug in the code and submitted a pull request. Waiting for approval before I mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the versions prior to 2.0.38

Simply update to a version of serilog-sinks-elasticsearch newer than 2.0.38.